# Diophantine relations using an equation with polynomials of degree at most 4

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, diophantine-equations

I'm completely stuck at exercise 5.8.5 of *Mathematical Logic*, Chiswell & Hodges:

[image]

Here are the mentioned definition and theorem:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm stuck because I failed to use the hint given in the exercise. I can't figure out how to use such a property of functions on a relation (a function is a relation but the opposite isn't true).  Also, I couldn't even figure out how this can be true for the following diophantine relation: "$x_1+x_2$ is a power of $5$".  The equation $\phi(x_1,x_2,y)$ for such a relation is $x_1+x_2=y^5$.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean "$x_1+x_2$ is a fifth power", that is,
$\exists y(x_1+x_2=y^5)$.

We want to say this: There exist $y, s, t, u, v$ such that $s=y^2$ and $t=sy$ and $u=ty$ and $v=uy$ such that $x_1+x_2=v$. This is equivalent to 
$$\exists y\exists s\exists t\exists u\exists v((s-y^2)^2+(t-sy)^2+(u-ty)^2+(v-uy)^2+(x_1+x_2-v)^2=0).\tag{1}$$
Note that the polynomial in (1) has degree $4$. Call it $P$. We are not quite finished, since $P$ contains minus signs. But we can rewrite $P=0$ as $Q=R$, where $Q$ and $R$ have positive coefficients (just bring the minus stuff in $P$ to the right-hand side).

The idea will work in general. We replace $z=y^{n+1}$, where $n$ is a *fixed* positive integer, by 
$$\exists t_1\cdots\exists t_{n}((t_1=y^2)\land (t_2=yt_1)\land \cdots \land (t_{n}=yt_{n-1})\land (z=t_n)).$$
Then (over the naturals, or the integers, or $\dots$) we use the sum of squares trick, $(a=b)\land (c=d)$ if and only if $(a-b)^2+(c-d)^2=0$.

*Remark*: This trick for  avoiding  high degree polynomials, but at the cost of introducing additional variables, occurs first, I believe, in the work of Skolem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I understand the trick thanks to you. I'm going to try using it and induction to solve the exercise. Your Remark is what you taught me through the exercise: introducing additional variables.

Comment: @Scientifica: You are welcome. Once upon a long time ago, I thought I had invented the trick.

Comment: :o that's impressive!

Comment: Using the result you are proving, one can show that there is no algorithm for determining whether $F(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ has a solution in integers, where $F$ is a quartic. By pushing a little more, one can show that there is no algorithm for determining whether $Q(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=1$ has a solution in integers, where $Q$ is a homogeneous quartic.

Comment: :o thank you for this comment. You gave an example of the importance of this result and that's nice. If I understand correctly, by showing that this result holds for quartics and using the exercise, we can conclude that there's no algorithm where $F$ is any polynomial (seems related to Hilbert's 10th problem), and I guess working on a particular case (quartic function) can make the proof easier. Since the problem reduces to quartics, I was quite tempted to think about it hhh.

Comment: @Scientifica:  It is an open problem whether there is an algorithm for solvability of cubics in integers. There is an algorithm for quadratics.

Comment: :o I see. You're right I made a mistake. There's no algorithm for solvability of diophantine equations doesn't mean there's no algorithm for solvability of some specific ones. So far I just started chapter 7 (First-Order Logic) in Chiswell & Hodges' book. Am I supposed to be able to prove the solvability of quadratics and unsolvability of quartics? If so that would be a nice exercise.

Comment: I believe I proved the solvability of quadratics. I got inspired from an algorithm that allows us to write any quadratic form as a linear combination in $\mathbb{R}$ of polynomials each of which is the square of a polynomial of degree 1 with no constant term. I also needed to use an easy result due to Bezout's Identity (though I don't know its proof when there are more than 2 variables): there is an algorithm for solvability of a polynomial of degree 1 in integers: Let $P(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i+c$ be such a polynomial.

Comment: We can write $P(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0$ in the form $\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i=-c$. Let $d=\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n)$. If $d\,\bar{|}\,c$ then clearly no solution exists. On the other hand, if $d\,|\,c$ then according to Bezout's Identity, there exists a solution. So the algorithm would be computing $\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ (there exists an algorithm for that) and then checking if it divides $c$ or not (there exists an algorithm for that). Now let's move on to quadratics.

Comment: I proved by induction on the number of variables of $P$ that every quadratic in integers can be written in the form $\frac{1}{c}P$ where $c\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\}$ and $P$ is the sum of the squares of polynomials of degree 1 in integers plus a polynomial of degree 1 in integers. This is clearly known when there's 1 variable: If $P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ then we know that $P(x)=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a^2}$. Then we can write $P$ in the form $\frac{1}{4a^2}Q$ where $Q$ is in the form we said earlier. If $a=0$ then $P$ is already in that form.

Comment: Now suppose that result is true for quadratics with $n$ variables. Consider a quadratic $P(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})$. Clearly, we can write it in the form $Q(x_1,\dots,x_n)+x_{n+1}R(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ where $Q$ is of degree at most $2$ and $R$ is of degree at most $1$. By induction hypothesis, we can write $Q$ in the stated form. Now we have $x_{n+1}R(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^nb_ix_ix_{n+1}+b_{n+1}x_{n+1}^2$. We leave the term $b_{n+1}x_{n+1}^2$ as it is. Let $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. We use the identity $x_ix_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4}\left((x_i+x_{n+1})^2-(x_i-x_{n+1})^2\right)$ and the conclusion follows easly.

Comment: :o It seems I didn't pay attention to a certain case so I didn't prove at all the solvability of quadratics. But what I did allows us to test if a quadratic has a solution or not in some particular cases. According to what I proved by induction, we can write the quadratic equation $P(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0$ in the form $Q(x_1,\dots,x_n)=c$ where $c\in\mathbb{N}$ and $Q$ is a quadratic written as the linear combination in integers of the squares of polynomials of degree $1$ plus a polynomial of degree $1$ with no constant term (constant term of $P$ is represented by $c$).

Comment: $Q$ has the form $a_1P_1^2+\dots+a_mP_m^2$ where $P_1,\dots,P_m$ are polynomials in integers of degree $1$. If $\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_m)$ doesn't divide $c$ then no solution exists. Otherwise, we can find out if a solution exists or not in a specific case: when all the $a_i$ have the same sign. In fact, in this case, we first check if $c=0$ or $c$  has the same sign as the $a_i$, otherwise we would have the equality of two terms of opposite signs. If $c=0$ then $Q=0$ is equivalent to the system $P_1=0\land\dots\land P_m=0$ of polynomials of degree $1$ on integers.

Comment: Here again I didn't pay attention to something: we can know if each of these equations have a solution, but what about the system? If $c\neq 0$ then we can first solve $c=a_1y_1^2+\dots+a_my_m^2$ and then solve $P_1=y_1\land\dots\land P_m=y_m$. Here again I don't know how to deal with that. My knowledge in number theory is elementary and I didn't give enaugh time yet to ring theory.